# How to properly run a npm script with arguments

Tags: npm, run-script

I've written a small command line program with nodejs and I want to be able to type `npm run test` and run the program with the arguments below.

Typing the following command directly works,
`node.exe scrappee.js -u 'https://github.com/matutter/{}' -us 'cloggie, AirRocks-Flightcontroller' -s '$commit=li.commits > a > span, $sha=.right .commit-tease-sha' -pm .\test\example_parse_module.js`

But with the contents of my package.json as follows there is no output whatsoever.

```
"scripts": {
    "test" : "node.exe scrappee.js -u 'https://github.com/matutter/{}' -us 'cloggie, AirRocks-Flightcontroller' -s '$commit=li.commits > a > span, $sha=.right .commit-tease-sha' -pm .\\test\\example_parse_module.js"
}
```

How can I get the command `npm run test` to run the scrappee.js script with the these arguments?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The issue was from the single quote `'` being converted to "'" by npm when the arguments are forwarded, the solution was to replace them with double quotes like below.

```
"test" : "node.exe scrappee.js -u \"https://github.com/matutter/{}\" -us \"cloggie, AirRocks-Flightcontroller\" -s \"$commit=li.commits > a > span, $sha=.right .commit-tease-sha\" -pm \".\\test\\example_parse_module.js\""
```

Comment: if you are using cross-env unfortunately this does not help.
Does not work on mac `cross-env-shell mocha --require ts-node/register \"testUnit/**/*.test.ts\""`, still runs tests only if the first subdirectory. Work on mac `mocha --require ts-node/register \"testUnit/**/*.test.ts\""`

Comment: How did you figure out that single quotes were converted to 2 double quotes?