# How to pass string value argument to package.json script command

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, npm, environment-variables

How does one pass string values enclosed with quotations "value"

For instance if I have the below command (does not work)

```
FILE=./path/subpath CASE="run this test" npm run test:one
```

The first FILE param is valid since it's not enclosed with string quotes, whereas for the second one, I need to wrap the *run this test* within strings since I'm targeting a specific scenario where I need to retrieve the name of a test. It fails.

If I were to change my name to runthistest and not use string quotations, the script will work.

```
FILE=./path/subpath CASE=runthistest npm run test:one
```

Of-course, I do not want this... I would like the first example to work. Any suggestion?

Comment: escape the quotes as in accepted answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500744/how-to-properly-run-a-npm-script-with-arguments

Comment: @RobertRowntree how do I do that in bash/terminal when passing values