# Firebase emulators:exec with 'npm test' script returns immediately

Tags: firebase, npm, npm-scripts, firebase-tools

I'm running some React integration tests with npm, and need the Firebase emulator for them. I've set up my npm scripts as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "test:integration:runner": "cross-env RTL_SKIP_AUTO_CLEANUP=true FIREBASE_DATABASE_EMULATOR_HOST=\"localhost:9000\" FIREBASE_FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR_HOST=\"localhost:5001\" FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=\"localhost:9099\" react-scripts test ./src/integrationTests/App.spec.js --watchAll=false",
    "test:integration": "firebase emulators:exec 'npm run test:integration:runner'",
  },
```

However, when I run `npm run test:integration`, the script returns after about 1 second, with no errors. Here is the only ouput:

```
PS C:\Users\{userame}\{project}> npm run test:integration

> {project_name} test:integration
> firebase emulators:exec 'npm run test:integration:runner'    

PS C:\Users\{userame}\{project}>
```

The firebase emulator itself is working if I run it standalone, and I tested the integration test with the emulator already running, and that works as well. I tried running `firebase emulators:exec` with a different non-npm script (instead of `npm run test:integration:runner`) and it successfully spun up the emulator. Any idea what might be happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured this out soon after asking the question. It turns out you need to double quote the script.

So I changed

```
"test:integration": "firebase emulators:exec 'npm run test:integration:runner'",
```

to

```
"test:integration": "firebase emulators:exec \"npm run test:integration:runner\" ",
```

I'd like to understand why this works though. This is in Windows, and I'm not sure how single/double quote semantics in commands might differ from what I'm used to.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the fix.  This was driving me crazy. Single quotes work on my Mac but not my Windows box, where I run Git Bash. Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37501023/4564359  ?